# How to remove phpmyadmin login prompt

Tags: server, mysql, phpmyadmin, .htaccess

When I go to mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin/ I get a prompt to access that page, then another to login into phpmyadmin.

Suddenly I can't access the page (like if the password is wrong), I tried to Alter user indentified with, just in case I had the password wrong, didn't work

then I tried to modify the config to remove it completely setting these:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = TRUE;
```

Didn't work

I redid all this in case something was broken and needed to be fixed : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04.

Still nothing

I'm out of ideas, I can connect just fine using ssh, any tips would be much appreciated.

Thank you!